# std::sort using custom function that perform on pointer and value

Tags: c++, sorting, std, c++98

I want to sort a `std::vector` of objects `A` by their attribute `z`. I have some vector that contain some `A` and other that contain some pointers to `A`.

Reading the documentation of `std::sort` I was able to build my costum comparator (that is templated because `A` is not my only one object).

```
template<typename T> struct ZSort
{
  bool operator()(const T lhs, const T rhs) const { return lhs.z > rhs.z; }
};

std::sort(V.begin(), V.end(), ZSort<A>());
```

However I'm struggled at making a `ZSort` that either work with `std::vector<A>` or `std::vector<A*>` I tried to overload the operator but it does not compile.

```
template<typename T> struct ZSort
{
  bool operator()(const T lhs, const T rhs) const { return lhs.z > rhs.z; 
  bool operator()(const T* lhs, const T* rhs) const { return lhs->z > rhs->z ;}
}
```

Is there a solution without creating two structures?

**Edit** from @slava comment the correct way to call the sorting structure is

```
std::sort(V.begin(), V.end(), ZSort<A>());
```

and not

```
 std::sort(V.begin(), V.end(), ZSort<A*>());
```

Comment: How did it "not work"?

Comment: If `T` is a pointer, `lhs.z` and `rhz.z` don't make sense.

Comment: How does "My vector V can contains either some A or some pointers to A?" A single vector can only contain one type.

Comment: Please provide a [mcve].  As the commentators above have noted your question is currently unclear.

Comment: `V` does not contains either `A*` or `A` but I have vectors of `A` and vectors of `A*`

Comment: Cannot reproduce https://ideone.com/IWiyZP works fine for me, post [mcve]

Comment: When you sort the vector of `A*`'s do you use `std::sort(V.begin(), V.end(), ZSort<A>());` or `std::sort(V.begin(), V.end(), ZSort<A*>());`?

Comment: @NathanOliver `std::sort(V.begin(), V.end(), ZSort<A*>());` This is what I did wrongly and I understood that from @slava comment